# Writing a permutation as elementary transpositions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

1)

Consider $σ = 4213 = (143) = (13) ◦ (14) $ But how do I get it in terms of elementary transpositions.

I know there is this theorem which states: Let $s_i$ be the elementary transpositions for $S_n$. Then, for $i < j$ the transposition
$(i j)$ can be written $(i j) = s_{j−1}$$s_{j−2}$ $· · ·$$s_{i+1}$$s_i$$s_{i+1}$$ · · ·$$s_{j−2}$$s_{j−1}$

I also know that the answer according to the theorem is $s_2s_1s_2◦s_3s_2s_1s_2s_3$ but I dont understand how to apply the theorem to get this answer.

2)

For $σ = 4213$ the shortest word(elementary transposition) is $w_σ = s_3s_1s_2s_1$ (length 4).
We can get the shortest word by considering the number of intersections in the bipartite graph of $σ$ (I do not know how to draw the graph on here). But how exactly can do I make out which intersection corresponds to which elementary transposition?

3)

Could someone recommend a text book on this topic as my lectures are not very clear and the recommended course book does not include this area of discrete maths?

Answer (score 1):

I'll comment on 1:

You already know that $(143) = (13) \circ (14)$.

Now expand $(1,3)$ by the theorem: it is of the form $(i,j)$ for $i=1, j=3$.

The theorem says to start at $s_{j-1}$. As $j=3$, $j-1 = 2$. Then go on till $s_i = s_1$ and then go up again to $j-1 = 2$ again. So $s_2 s_1 s_2 = (13)$.

For $(14)$ we do the same with $j = 4$ (so $j-1 = 3$) and $i=1$ again: $s_3 s_2 s_1 s_2 s_3$.

It's a matter of reading the formula from the theorem in the right way (filling in the dots, almost literally).